# Java file upload : cannot find symbol - getSubmittedFileName()

Tags: java

I'm trying to retrieve a file from a JSP form.
I'm using Tomcat 9.0 / Java 8

When I compile, I got the messages :

> addHabit.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
> String fileName =  Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
> symbol:   method getSubmittedFileName()
> location: variable filePart of type Part

> addHabit.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
> String fileName =  Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
> symbol:   variable Paths

My code is pretty simple and looks like everything I found here and on the web :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

// Appelé par le JSP addConfigType.jsp via l'action du formulaire

@MultipartConfig(
  fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1, // 1 MB
  maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,      // 10 MB
  maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100   // 100 MB
)
public class addHabit extends HttpServlet{ 
 
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     
        String url="myURL";
        
        Part filePart = request.getPart("monfichier");          
        String fileName =  Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();             
         for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            part.write(url);                
        }
    }
}
```

I compile using javax.servlet-api-3.0.1
According to this post
[How can I upload files to a server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-can-i-upload-files-to-a-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)
it should be fine

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#getSubmittedFileName--) state:

```
Since:
Servlet 3.1
```

that means that your `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1` is too old. There is a version [3.1.0 available](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0).

I just realized that the question you linked also provides these answers already, as well as a copy-pastable workaround, have you read that question and answer?

Comment: Wow, I read it so many time ...
Thx a lot, it solve the first error but it still is unable to find 'Paths', any idea on this one ?

Comment: You need to `import java.nio.file.Paths;`